# Open Graph "Price" and "ID"

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to implement the Open Graph protocoll into my e-commerce. I have 2 alerts regarding problems to fix:

<< Property price is incorrectly formatted >>
Does it mean that I need to switch all the prices with "." to separate decimals instead of ","?

<< Products without "id" information can't be uploaded. Please check that this field is included for each product in a separate, labeled column. >>
This is something I don't really understand.

Any tips/suggestions?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: please add an example of your current open graph tags.

Comment: Hi,
something like this:
<meta name="title" content="{product_name}">
<meta property="og:title" content="{product_name}">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en-en">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MobiliRebecca">
<meta property="og:image" content="{cover_image_link}">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mobilirebecca.it/it/">
<meta name="description" content="{short_description}">
<meta property="og:description" content="{short_description}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{product_tags}">

Comment: always add relevant information to your question, never in comments. and use the code formatting option.